# spring cloud configuration client spamming our configuration server

Tags: spring-cloud

We have a set of micro services which obtain their configuration from a configuration server that we have created.  Our configuration server uses mongo as the backing store for configuration files and we run it in a redundant configuration so that if any of the configuration servers fail then we can fail over to another.

Now the configuration for each service is that it uses discovery to get the location of the configuration server.  We can see that each service obtains a reference ants the proper configuration data for the server and that all services start correctly with this data.

Now one thing that we noticed is that the services regularly request their configurations from the configuration server every 3 mins.  This is being done at the configuration client level and not in our code base.

This get request from every service at that rate is causing quite a bit of load on the configuration service.  Is this expected and if so how can be lower the rate of these pings?

One additional issue is that if we make a health request to any service, this triggers a request to get the services configuration from the remote configuration service.

The combination of both of these elements is driving our configuration server into the ground since they are 5 requests/sec on the server.

Comment: Config client does not poll the config server. The health check does. Do you have some monitoring that regularly hits the health check?

Comment: yes, we do. We notice that the health check seems to do a get of the configuration from the config server.  Can this health check be less heavy since a get of the parameters does a get form mongo (in our case), etc.

Comment: we use the services discovered in eureka to berate through them and get the health status for external monitoring tools.  with 30 services at an interval of 30 seconds that adds up

Comment: You can disable the health check. I'll have to find the config later.

Comment: Is it possible to customize the health indicator for the config client. Based on our own custom config server I have something in mind